# Deleting checked records from table in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am not able to recognize what I am doing wrong in my code. Can someone help ? I want to delete all the images which are checked using c# .

my code snippet looks like this :-

```
SqlConnection con = new            
SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ConnectionString);
SqlDataAdapter adap;
DataSet ds;
string Query;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        binddata();

    }
}

protected void binddata()
{

    string str = "select * from photos";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);

    adap = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds);
    Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

con.Open();
String mySQL;


try
{

    for (int i = 0; i < Repeater1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)
        Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (((CheckBox)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked)
        {

            //This assumes data type of messageID is integer, change (int) to the right type
            CheckBox CheckBox = (CheckBox)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
            Literal litMessageId = (Literal)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("literal1");

            string Id = litMessageId.Text;
            mySQL = string.Format("delete from photos where id = '{0}'", Id);

            SqlCommand cmdDelete = new SqlCommand(mySQL, con);
            cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();




            // Continue your code here
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }


}
    catch
{
    Label2.Text = "errror";
}

}
```

.aspx page contains :-

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
         <img src='images/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"images") %>' height="150" width="150" alt="" border="0" />
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

           </br>
        </ItemTemplate>


        </asp:Repeater>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: and the exception is...?

Comment: Can you debug and see what's the value for Id ??

Comment: if there is no exception you must be passing the wrong id.

Comment: btw  <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
has no bound value to it , how it will return you the ID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some pointers:

The names you use are difficult to understand in your codebehind. You now have 1 repeater but in case you have multiple it is better to use a more specific name.

Depending on the .NET version you can use generic types to declare your variables.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
```

becomes:

```
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connectionString);
```

Your not closing the connection. If your in newer versions of .NET the best approach would in my opinion be:

```
private string ConnectionString  = webConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"] != null ? WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString : "";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ConnectionString))
{
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
{
    //your code here
}
}
```

You are catching an error but your not doing anything with the provided information.

use:

```
Catch (Exception exception)
{
    ErrorLabel.Text = string.format("The following error has occurred: {0}.", exception.Message);
}
```

to use the exception.Message where desired.

In modern implementations you are most probably better off using an MVC application using EntityFramework and MVC Razor.

Defining your SQL queries like that is dangerous also. If I edit the post value of the literal to something like "ID AND 1 = 1" I will now delete all photos.

Here are some pages to help you get started with Entityframework and MVC:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B

I will give you some good pointers in improvements in a minute. First try this and change the literal value to the column you use as an id in case I got it wrong:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    <img src='images/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"images") %>' height="150" width="150" alt="" border="0" />
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"id") %>'></asp:Literal>
    </br>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>



SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ConnectionString);
SqlDataAdapter adap;
DataSet ds;
string Query;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        binddata();
    }
}

protected void binddata()
{
    string str = "select * from photos";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);

    adap = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds);
    Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    String mySQL;
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Repeater1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("CheckBox1")
            Literal litMessageId = (Literal)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("literal1");

            if (CheckBox1 != null && litMessageId != null && CheckBox1.Checked)
            {
                string Id = litMessageId.Text;
                mySQL = string.Format("delete from photos where id = '{0}'", Id);

                SqlCommand cmdDelete = new SqlCommand(mySQL, con);
                cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Continue your code here
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Label2.Text = "error";
    }
}
```